# MongoDB schema design with C# driver?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Any ideas on how to represent the following with .net objects?

```
{
    _id: ’T4Y...AC’, // base64-encoded ObjectId
    name: ’Rick’,
    profile: { ... age, location, interests, etc. ... },
    followers: {
    "T4Y...AD": { name: ’Jared’, circles: [ ’python’, ’authors’] },
    "T4Y...AF": { name: ’Bernie’, circles: [ ’python’ ] },
    "T4Y...AI": { name: ’Meghan’, circles: [ ’python’, ’speakers’ ] }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the Mongo "introduction" documents were a little better, people wouldn't have to ask like this. http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial is quite lacking when it comes to automatic serialization.

Comment: And yes, *I know*, MongoDB uses JSON primarily as a way to show data from and store data to the database, and that document appears to give pretty good example of MongoDB's basic types, but generally I'm not working on JSON from scratch.

Comment: (the OPs question isn't even using strict JSON... is this even valid in MongoDB? I don't even know.)

Comment: @JayC: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial.  What's missing from this?

Comment: @Game99 why do you want to base64 encode the object id? You can apply a BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String) attribute on it and it will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks Craig... maybe it was some stupidity on my part but that never came up in my searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine it might look something like

```
[DataContract]
public class data
{
    [BsonId]
    [DataMember(Order = 0]
    public BsonObjectId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 1]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2]
    public Profile profile { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 3]
    public Dictionary<string,Follower> followers { get; set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class Profile
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0]
    public int age { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 1]
    public string location { get ;set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2]
    public string interests { get ;set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Follower
{

     [DataMember(Order = 0]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 1]
    public string[] circles
}
```

I believe both Mongo and WCF support dictionaries so yes you could change Followers to a dictionary

Comment: I'm figuring "followers" actually translates to a dictionary type, but seeing this apparently is using WCF "Serializable" notation, I'm not sure how that translates off the top of my head.   Last time I tried to deal with dictionaries in WCF it was a bit wonky, though doable.

Comment: You might want to edit your question to include that its working with WCF. I will update my answer

Comment: All the DataContract classes can go away and the DataMembers can become BsonElement() -> if you want to change the name of an element, you can include it in the ctor of the BsonElement attribute.

Comment: I have had troubles with MongoDB serializing dictionaries in the right way.

Comment: @CraigWilson I had tried this and the BsonElement Tag it still didnt serialize. (I want to use camel case in my db json and pascal case in my c# code) Have you seen this method work for serialization?